# Unable to link UITable delegate to File Owner in IB of xcode

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios4, delegates

I am facing an issue and that is -

I am using tabBarCpntroller in my application. In this there are just two views. Both the views have tables in that.

I am able to display and populate the table in the first view but as I try to connect the delegate of UITable in the IB for the second view and then run the code, it crashes.

PS: I am using the same code as in first view.

Kindly help me out with the suggestions, I would be highly grateful

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Can you show some code where you declared the tableview,i feel you are missing some points in the same.

Comment: How are you creating views for tabBarController. Using XIB or by manual coding. Note: When you are having tables inside the tabs, first you have to create navigation controller, then have the table view inside navigation controller. so that on click of tableview, you can navigate to next view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the looks of your question, you need UITableView, not UITable, if this is what you are using, then you will have problems.

in your header, you must define your **`UITableView`** as an **`IBOutlet`**.

### .h

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController  <UITableViewDelegate,                                                                 UITableViewDataSource>
{
    IBOutlet UITableView *myTable;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITableView *myTable;
@end
```

Once you have done this, build (only) your code, then Interface Builder will see that outlet and you can connect it.